# How to logout from microsoft in xamarin forms?

Tags: authentication, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, forms-authentication

I am working on xamarin forms. Where login is through Microsoft using **AuthenticationContext**. Once I click on login button it will redirect to a Microsoft login page. login is working properly. Once I logged in from the user on logout button click user should be logged out, how to do logout no button click?

using the following code I am able to login

```
public Task<AuthenticationResult> Authenticate(string authority, string resource, string clientId, string returnUri)
    {
        try
        {
            var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
            if (authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().Any())
            {
                authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().First().Authority);
            }


            var uri = new Uri(returnUri);
            var platformParams = new PlatformParameters((Activity)Forms.Context);
            var authResult = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, uri, platformParams);
            return authResult;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Crashes.TrackError(ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Please help me how to log out?

Comment: Hey Sagar, your question is not clear "how to do logout no button click?" Why would a user logout without a button click?

Comment: Do you mean to exit automatically? You can elaborate on what is required for automatic exit.

Comment: Here is a document for reference. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/azure#logging-out-users

Answer (score 2):

You `Logout` by clearing the Tokencache, and then exit the app, or set the App MainPage to Login Page.

For iOS:

```
public async Task LogoutAsync()
        {
            var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
            if (authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().Any())
            {
                authContext.TokenCache.Clear();
            }

            //In addition to clearing the token cache, you should also clear the cookies in the web view.
            //Otherwise, the session cookies come into play and that is why you are seeing the web view come up and disappear immediately.
            foreach (var cookie in NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage.Cookies)
            {
                NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage.DeleteCookie(cookie);
            }
        }
```

Same For Android, just difference method to clear cookie:

```
        CookieManager.Instance.RemoveAllCookie();
```

Comment: Yes it is working fine. I want to know how to pass a hint email with authority? For example in my app in my application first, we are asking the user to enter an email. Once the user enters an email we will check in DB that user exists in our DB or not? If yes we are redirecting to Microsoft login page. There we should ask only for the password, email Id should binded automatically based on the text in the input box. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Clearing access token to get logout

```
Public static void Logout()
{
  AuthenticationContext authContext = new 
  AuthenticationContext(AuthenticationConstants.Authority);
  TokenCache tokenCache = ac.TokenCache;
  tokenCache.Clear();
}
```

call this method before back to login page.I mean before navigating back to login page you have to clear the access token

```
Like example
private void NavigateToLoginViewController()
{ 
    // call the above logout method here 
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Comment: Yes it is working fine. I want to know how to pass a hint email with authority? For example in my app in my application first, we are asking the user to enter an email. Once the user enters an email we will check in DB that user exists in our DB or not? If yes we are redirecting to Microsoft login page. There we should ask only for the password, email Id should binded automatically based on the text in the input box. How to achieve this?